# Moving laravel project to another directory

Tags: windows, laravel, xampp

I just installed laravel. I use Windows Xampp.
Currently I installed it in c:\users\user_name\laravel.
Is that correct or should I put it in htdocs?
If so how to do it?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut paste you laravel project in path to xampp\htdocs . set root folder of xampp to xampp\htdocs\laravel\public

Comment: after cut and paste my project
it leads me to another error, 
Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I try to change env configuration about database and user name, then it leads me again to another error..
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Comment: in your AppServiceProvider.php in providers, inside boot method, you have to put this code Schema::defaultStringLength(191); its a laravel bug

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to syam who helped me to start finding a fix to my problem.
Here is my solution

1. Move laravel project to htdocs
2. Change the env configuration DB_DATABASE=your_db_name DB_USERNAME=user_name DB_PASSWORD=user_password
3. Edit AppServiceProvider.php and add this code

   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
   public function boot()
   {
       Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
   }
4. Then in command line move the active directory to your laravel project and execute this code

> composer install
>
> php artisan key:generate
>
> php artisan cache:clear
>
> php artisan migrate

Answer (score 0):

On moving laravel project to another directory:
To clear cache, sometimes permission problem may occur. Do this serially:

change env values then,

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan migrate
```